# Invalid use of group function. Error Code 1111

Tags: mysql

I am trying to write a procedure that makes an update to the table by adding a column that is foreign key, but returns error. What could be wrong?

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS tbl_file_add_column_instance_id;
DELIMITER //
    CREATE PROCEDURE tbl_file_add_column_instance_id()
    BEGIN
        IF NOT EXISTS((SELECT column_name FROM information_schema.columns 
        WHERE table_name = 'tbl_file' AND table_schema = 'diginet2' AND column_name = 'instance_id'))
        THEN
            ALTER TABLE tbl_file ADD COLUMN instance_id INT NOT NULL AFTER id;
            ALTER TABLE tbl_file ADD CONSTRAINT id_instance_arq FOREIGN KEY (`instance_id`) REFERENCES `diginet2`.`tbl_instance` (`id`)
                    ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION;
            -- Set rows that already exist
            SET @query_initial_instance := (SELECT @initial_instance:=id FROM diginet.tbl_instance WHERE instance_status = 1 LIMIT 1);
            IF COUNT(@query_initial_instance) = 1
            THEN
                UPDATE tbl_file SET instance_id = @initial_instance;
            ELSE
                -- fake throw error
                SELECT * FROM diginet_has_none_or_more_than_one_instance;
            END IF;
        END IF; 
    END //
DELIMITER ;

CALL tbl_file_add_column_instance_id();
```

and I am getting this error: Error Code 1111. Invalid use of group function

Comment: Please edit your question and post the full error message.

Comment: Why are you using `COUNT`? Just use `IF @query_initial_instance = 1`

Comment: The count will always be 1 because of `LIMIT 1`.

Comment: @Barmar `LIMIT 1` can also return zero rows.

Comment: If you want to tell if the query returned anything, use `IF @query_initial_instance IS NOT NULL`

Comment: Another way to do it is `SELECT @count := COUNT(*) FROM ...`

Comment: @PaulSpiegel Good point. What I meant was that it can never be more than 1, so this can't distinguish between 1 and more than 1, as the `ELSE` clause suggests is intended.

Comment: Well we will probably never find out, what this line is supposed to do :-) - I'm betting on `IF @query_initial_instance IS NOT NULL THEN UPDATE tbl_file SET instance_id = @query_initial_instance;`

Comment: BTW: You can't `ADD` a `NOT NULL` column without a default value to a non-empty table.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know how many rows match the `WHERE` condition, you should use `COUNT()` in the query, not the `IF` statement.

```
SET @row_count = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM diginet.tbl_instance WHERE instance_status = 1)
IF @row_count = 1
THEN 
    UPDATE tbl_file SET instance_id = (SELECT id FROM digitnet.tbl_instance WHERE intance_status = 1);
ELSE
    -- fake throw error
    SELECT * FROM diginet_has_none_or_more_than_one_instance;
END IF
```

I don't think there's a legal way to get the count and the sole value in a single query. You could do:

```
SELECT @row_count := COUNT(*), @initial_instance:=id FROM diginet.tbl_instance WHERE instance_status = 1;
```

But this violates the `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` rule.